# Visual aid in drag and drop within a ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, drag-and-drop

### Problem

I have two ListView's. One has options that are to be dragged into the other. This is the "fields" ListView. The other one is the "builder" ListView. I cannot figure out a way to visually show the user where the item will be inserted. I would like to draw a line in-between the ListViewItem's to visually aid the user.

```
private void builder_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void fields_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void fields_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
    fromBuilder = false;
    fields.DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
}

private void builder_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
    fromBuilder = true;
    builder.DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
}

private void builderAndFields_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem i = new ListViewItem();
    i = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListViewItem)) as ListViewItem;

    // Since this function works for both the builder and the fields,
    // we have to check to see where we are dropping, the sender
    // is the ListView we are dropping onto
    if (sender.Equals(builder))
    {
        ListViewItem c = new ListViewItem();
        c = (ListViewItem)i.Clone();
        Point cp = builder.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        Console.WriteLine("cp: " + cp);
        ListViewItem dragToItem = builder.GetItemAt(cp.X, cp.Y);
        Console.WriteLine("dragToItem: " + dragToItem);
        int dropIndex = dragToItem.Index;
        // Now, we have to check to see if we are reordering or adding
        // So, we check the flag to see if the dragDrop was initiated 
        // on the builder or on the fields ListView
        if (fromBuilder)
        {
            builder.Items.Insert(dropIndex, c);
            builder.Items.Remove(i);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dropIndex);
            builder.Items.Insert(dropIndex, c);
        }
    }
    // If the sender is the fields listView, the user is trying to remove
    // the item from the builder.
    else
    {
        builder.Items.Remove(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PreviewDragEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.uielement.previewdragenter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [PreviewDragOver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.uielement.previewdragover%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and [PreviewDragLeave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.uielement.previewdragleave%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You can use that event to add an Adorner to your drop list. IF you search for "WPF DragDropHelper" you will find several detailed examples.

Comment: This does not work for C# Windows Forms applications as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

[Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) supports [drop highlighting and insertion marks](http://www.componentowl.com/documentation/better-listview/data/chapter-drag-drop.html) out of the box:

[image]

I think you can also do this in a regular ListView using **HitTest()** method within **DragOver** event handler.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to pay that kind of cash for this functionality. I will see what I can do with HitTest().

Comment: You can also try [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express), which is free. It comes with a lot of samples, including usage of insertion mark and drag-drop.